# Compiling and loading kernel module drivers with Yocto

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, yocto

I'm compiling a Linux kernel and root file system for a Dart board from this manual:
http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=VAR-SOM-MX6_Yocto_Fido_New_R2

Now, I want to include extra drivers for attaching a WiFi USB dongle to my compiled version. I figured out how to compile the modules myself with the kernel `Makefile`, but I want them to be compiled and packaged with the RFS when I run `bitbake` on the project. I know the names of the kernel objects I need - `ath.ko`, `ath9k.ko`, `ath9k_common.ko`, `ath0k_hw.ko` and `ath9k_htc.ko`.

I have no prior experience with Yocto, so I would appreciate a somewhat detailed explanation.

So my questions are, given the kernel objects / modules / drivers I need:

- How do I make Yocto compile them when compiling the kernel?
- How do I make Yocto package the resulting compiled kernel modules in the RFS image it creates?

Answer (score 1):

Clean up the Kernel sstate-cache
`bitbake -c cleansstate kernelName`

To do configuration to the kernel, you could use this command

`bitbake kernelName -c menuconfig`

Then, Compile the kernel after configuration

`bitbake kernelName`

There is a kernel lab tutorial in Yocto that teaches the basic of kernel configuration, available [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/sites/default/files/kernel-lab-1.4.pdf).

Comment: There is no need to compile a kernel if it's already been compiled. Module compilation is usually sufficient.

Comment: I recompile the kernel all the time with Yocto if I need to change or add stuff.  The thing is, I do not see single module compilation in Yocto.  You might find a better way to do this, please advise.

Comment: @LightenS it might be a stupid question, but what are the options for `kernelName`? I know what version I have, but I'm not sure if it has a "name" and what is it.

Comment: the kernelName I referred is the Package Name of the kernel.  In this link, you would see a list of kernel recipes from meta-fsl-arm-extra.  Kernel is treated like a recipe in Yocto.  so any thing before the "undercore" is used as package name or Recipe Name.  For example, linux-wandboard, linux-toradex, linux-boundary. https://github.com/Freescale/meta-fsl-arm-extra/tree/master/recipes-kernel/linux

Comment: @LightenS, I don't know the specific way for Yocto, but kernel itself is **modular**, thus most of the drivers you may build out of tree or in the same tree without recompiling entire kernel.

Comment: "bitbake virtual/kernel" should be generic