# Add single LKM to Yocto build

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, yocto

I am working on a Yocto build for a Variscite MX6.  I have [followed the instructions](http://variwiki.com/index.php?title=VAR-SOM-MX6_Yocto_Fido_R2_Build_Yocto_release) and can build a bootable image for the board using "bitbake core-image-minimal", which I can login to and use.  At this point, I need to add a single LKM to the image. What is the straightforward way to create a layer that extends what is here and adds the single LKM?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726829/compiling-and-loading-kernel-module-drivers-with-yocto) addresses how to do this if the module is included in the kernel.  In this case, the LKM is provided by a vendor, so I don't think it is as simple as running menuconfig.

Comment: [HERE](http://wiki.kaeilos.com/index.php/Howto_build_a_kernel_module_out_of_the_kernel_tree) you can find a very basic example of how to compile and add a kernel module using Yocto. Start thinking to create your new layer at Yocto sources. Another option is to isolate Kernel source code and add kernel module into it.

Comment: Okay, I've seen similar before, this is just a bit better.  I think part of my problem is I am not sure whether creating a layer is the right answer.  Your comment suggests it is.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt I understand your question but what I have summoned
answer is
to build your own LKM(linux kernel module)
follow this [link](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6.1/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#incorporating-out-of-tree-modules)

and other point its not as simple as

> In this case, the LKM is provided by a vendor, so I don't think it is as simple as running menuconfig.

you have not specified which driver you are talking about
I am not able to help there

but there are plenty of devices are supported by linux and if not in kernel tree you can always ask your vendor for driver 
and worst case you do not getr that support search internet for support for that driver for your linux kernel version (if version is differant you can still modify and make it support) and 
Lastly
Final choice is write your own code and use above method as I have provided in link to compile that driver

Hope You will figure out a solution and 
All the best for this project